# window object does not recognise 'require fetch api'

Tags: javascript, window

My goal is to record my voice and based the keyword 'weather' call the DarkSkyApi, to print out the current weather conditions in the frontend.

status quo: I can print out my voice recording to the screen in index.html and I can access the DarkSkyAPI in a seperate script.js and fetch the data I want.

However I am struggeling with calling the API based on a keyword that is recorded by window.SpeechRecognition.

I tried this:
1. when I copy the script into the HTML, require.js is not recognised
2. when I keep the script seperate in a script.js file, the window object is not recognised

index.html

```
    window.SpeechRecognition = window.SpeechRecognition || 
    window.webkitSpeechRecognition;
...
    // Speech to text: Voice is recognised and words are printed on the screen 
 ...

    // based on the keyword 'weather', call the DarkSkyAPI with fetch and print out current weather conditions

    if (transcript.includes('weather')) {
    let fetch = require('node-fetch');
    let req = new fetch.Request(uri, options);

fetch(req)
    .then((res) => {
        if (res.ok) {
            return res.json();

        } else {
            throw new Error('Bad HTTP!')
        }
    }).then((json) => {
        console.log('json', json.currently.temperature, json.currently.summary);
        console.log('JSON Provided')
        weatherSummary.innerHTML = json.currently.summary;
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log('ERROR:', err.message);
    });
}
```

Comment: `require` does not exist in the browser, `fetch` does, just remove your `require` line

Comment: When I remove the ```require``` I get the following error message: ```index.html:91 Uncaught TypeError: fetch.Request is not a constructor
    at SpeechRecognition.<anonymous> ```

Comment: Oh yeah, `let req = new fetch.Request(uri, options);` is not how `fetch` work:
`fetch('http://my-url.com/some/path', { /* options if apply */ })` instead of `fetch(req)`

Comment: Thank you @kigiri, changing the fetch url to fetch(`https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://api.darksky.net/forecast/....`) worked!

Answer (score 0):

In order to make an API call to DarkSkyAPI based on a keyword that is recorded with the window object SpeechRecognition, I had to delete `require` and rewrite my fetch to `fetch(https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://api.darksky.net/forecast/....)`, which removed the CORS and CORB issues.

new script inside index.html:

```
fetch(`https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://api.darksky.net/forecast/${key}/${lat},${lang}?units=ca`)
      .then((res) => {
          if (res.ok) {
              return res.json();
          } else {
              throw new Error('Bad HTTP! res 1 not ok')
          }
      }).then((json) => {
                weatherSummary.innerHTML = `${json.currently.summary} ${json.currently.temperature}`;
      })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log('ERROR:', err.message);
        });
   }
```

});`